# How to make a movie clip invisible depending on a value in another layer?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make an "achievements" page for my game, where if the user has a high score greater than 100, then the achievement can be unlocked. I tried using a code like this, but it didn't seem to work!

```
function Check();
if(endscreen_mc.highscore_txt > 100)
{
medals.roachLock.visible = false;
}
else if(endscreen_mc.highscore_txt < 100)
{
medals.roachLock.visible = true;
}
else if(endscreen_mc.visible == 100)
{
medals.roachLock.visible = true;
}
```

The high score value is saved inside a shared object. What's wrong with my code, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the type of the `endscreen_mc.highscore_txt` property? If it is a `TextField`, you'll first need to access the `text` property of the textfield and cast it to a `Number` like so:

```
var score:Number = Number(endscreen_mc.highscore_txt.text); // this casts the String value of the text property to a Number

if(score > 100)
{
    medals.roachLock.visible = false;
}
else
{
    medals.roachLock.visible = true;
}
```

Additionally I've simplified the if/else statement. Now if the score is not greater than 100, the lock will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

visible property in ActionScript is type Boolean - meaning that it can have only values "true" or "false", so your third statement

> else if(endscreen_mc.visible == 100)

will not work. Mabye you wanted to put there

> endscreen_mc.highscore_txt

Also, one important thing, your function Check(); doesn't have a body, meaning that each actionscript function looks like this:

```
function functionName(){}//your if statement goes between curly brackets.
```

So if I'm getting this right this is what your function should look like:

```
function Check(){
    if(endscreen_mc.highscore_txt > 100){
        medals.roachLock.visible = false;
    } else {
        medals.roachLock.visible = true;
    }
}
```